# JMeter - How to pick given number of rows from CSV to send in HTTP request body

Tags: apache, csv, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

My test case is to send a given number of rows in sequence from CSV file to HTTP request body in each request. I tried using **CSV Data Set Config** but it allowing read only single row for each request.
Is it possible to read data from CSV in given batch (eg. 5 simple comma separated plain text rows in each request body) using JMeter ?.

Let's say I have CSV file `test.csv` with 10 records.

```
no,name,email
1,test,test@test.com
2,test,test@test.com
3,test,test@test.com
4,test,test@test.com
5,test,test@test.com
6,test,test@test.com
7,test,test@test.com
8,test,test@test.com
9,test,test@test.com
10,test,test@test.com
```

Now I want to send 2 rows (simple comma separated plain text rows) from this CSV to JMeter HTTP request body. Is it possible using JMeter?

I tried using CSV Data Set Config but it doesn't provide such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [__CSVRead](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function to get more than 1 row using `next` as second parameter:

> For example, you could set up some variables as follows:

> - COL1a ${__CSVRead(random.txt,0)}
> - COL2a ${__CSVRead(random.txt,1)}${__CSVRead(random.txt,next)}
> - COL1b ${__CSVRead(random.txt,0)}
> - COL2b ${__CSVRead(random.txt,1)}${__CSVRead(random.txt,next)}

Answer (score -1):

This is a very custom use case therefore you have to go for scripting using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

Example syntax:

```
${__groovy(new File('test.csv').readLines().subList(1\,3).join('\,'),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hey @Dmitri T, Where to add this script code?.  Inside BeanShell Preprocessor?

Comment: I am getting this exeption while executing above. Response code: 500
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script16.groovy: 1: unexpected token: 1 @ line 1, column 1.
   1,test,test@test.com,2,test,test@test.com
   ^

1 error

Comment: is it possible to pick two rows in sequence from csv. Let's say the first request has first two rows and the next request have next two rows.

Comment: Hi @rajesh, were you able to figure this out? I am also stuck in a similar problem of picking the whole csv rows rather than one at a time. My HTTP request endpoint support bulk records, so one at a time is not optimal.